# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Organisation to type 'Site.Models.Person'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
 try
        {
            person = (Person) database.People.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Username == User.Identity.Name);
          //  m_objLog.Debug("Found user :" + User.Identity.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            m_objLog.Debug(ex.Message);
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
```

And My Person Model is bellow

```
protected override void Initialize() {
            base.Initialize();
            EmailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>();
            TelephoneNumbers = new List<TelephoneNumber>();
}
[InverseProperty("Person")]
        public virtual List<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Person")]
        public virtual List<TelephoneNumber> TelephoneNumbers { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
[InverseProperty("People")]
        public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
```

I am not sure why it is producing error; am I not casting properly in 
                person = (Person) database.People.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Username == User.Identity.Name);

Please advice.

Comment: What type is `database.People`? And why are you explicitly casting?

Comment: Hi Haim; could you please tell me   [InverseProperty("People")]
        public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Organisation")]
        [ForeignKey("Organisation")]
        public int? OrganisationId { get; set; } -- is not causing problem

Comment: InverseProperty people inside the Person class

Comment: its not showing error in Dev but when I am publishing into iis showing above error

Comment: Seems like you're using `[InverseProperty]` incorrectly. You set it on 3 different properties with the same name ("People").

Comment: As I know I can have multiple InverseProperty with having same name.

Comment: public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

A "person" is linked to a specific organization.

An "organization" cannot be linked to a specific person.  (It would not make sense.)

In ORM, an "organization" can be seen as having a set of persons who are associated with it, but that relationship is encoded in the "person belongs to organization" relationship. (By means of the `[InverseProperty]` annotation.)

Therefore, it is wrong to say the following:

```
[InverseProperty("People")]
public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
```

There can be no "inverse property here".  It does not make any sense.  And it could not possibly work, because it would be a circular relationship definition: it is like telling the ORM to look at the organization of a person in order to figure out the persons of the organization, but then also to look at the persons of an organization in order to figure out the organization of a person.

So, just strip the `[InverseProperty("People")]` line.

Comment: Hi @Mike Nakis I have tried your approach but still not working. I have 2 different databases in 2 different test environment. it is absolutely working fine in one but not in other even both databases are copied from live so both are identical and same sql server version.

Comment: This then becomes a totally different question having to do with some databases copied from some live into some test environments etc.